# SQL error 46010: Incorrect syntax near?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2014

I am facing an error in my database project's "refactor log" file. At the first line it gives an error `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` The error code is sql46010. I couldn't find anything useful related to this error. Can anybody help?

Comment: I think you really need to show us the code/query which is causing this error.

Comment: And mention which DB are you using...

Comment: I am using sql server 2014 and its the first line "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>" that is causing error

Comment: What are you trying to do? SQL Server internally uses  "utf-16". You cannot declare your own encoding with datatype XML.

Comment: Got the same error when renaming a column in my Db project with Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2 and Server Data Tools 14.0.60311.1.
A dbProject.refactorlog file was automatically generated, but I now have a Build error SQL46010 at the first line of this XML file

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the **Project==>Properties==>Build Action** for the xml file is set to **"None"** and this will remove the error and allow the project to build successfully.

[image: Build Action Set to None]

As mentioned in the answer above, excessive warnings may cause an issue as well, you can suppress specific warnings that are not helpful by doing the following:

[image: Suppress Specific Warnings]

Or by increasing the number of allowed warnings under **"Tools==>Options==>SQL Server Tools==>General"**:

[image: Increase Maximum Warning Limit]

Answer (score 0):

as said before, I encountered the same error, but managed to solve it.
The problem was that I had **more than 200 warnings**, so VS stopped checking the existing errors.

Either fix your warnings, or find Options to disable some of them. I unchecked **Validate Casing on Identifiers** in the project > **Properties**. That change removed almost 150 warnings, so my project could build again.

Answer (score 0):

This might help some in the future, i had the same error in my database vs project when it was built in Azure CI pipeline. The build just failed to finish. However building the project locally worked well. The project was targetting 2019 sql server platform.

I reviewed the pipeline deployment pool and changed it to use win-2019 (Azure pipelines instead of hosted pipelines). This built the project successfully in Azure CI pipeline.